# problems with a simple coordinate conversion

Tags: math

This code is supposed to calculate and return the real part of a complex number with magnitude a and angle b in degrees. It gives me wrong numbers.

```
        x = (a*(cos(b*(180/pi))));
```

This however, gives me the right numbers if the angle is given in radians.

> x = (a*(cos(b)));

pi is defined as const double pi = 3.142

Any thoughts? I cannot see why the x should be wrong in the first but correct in the second example.

Answer (score 2):

Since 180 degrees is 1 pi radian. The formula for degrees to radians should be

radian = (degree / 180) pi.

Thus the first formula should be

```
x = (a*(cos((b / 180)*pi))));
```

Comment: thank you. I knew I was just doing something stupid.

Answer (score 1):

You have the conversion backwards: your formula changes `b` from radians to degrees before calculating its cosine. But you want to convert from degress to radians. The correct formula is

```
 x = (a*(cos(b*(pi/180)));
```

though you could use fewer parentheses and use more spacing:

```
 x = a * cos(b * pi / 180);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using formula correctly

this can be written as:

x = (a*cos((b * pi)/180));